# What elements of the world reset when I respawn at a checkpoint?

Tags: hitman-absolution

So I murdered a cop for his uniform the other day.  I had planned to use it to infiltrate a strip club and murder the owner, but on the way, I realized that I'd be better off dressed as a bouncer. Luckily, there was a bouncer in a secluded area nearby.  I let the alive out of him and absconded with his uniform.

A minute later I activated a checkpoint.  Shortly afterward, I got killed.

"Aha!" says I.  "I'm still wearing the bouncer disguise!".  Expecting (reasonably, one might say) the area to still be clear, I ran through and was promptly shot to death by the bouncer, miraculously re-alive and not even a little bit stabbed (or naked)!

**What elements of the world reset after I respawn at a checkpoint?**

Comment: I wouldn't really know, i never respawned at a checkpoint, when feces hit the fan I just start killing anything that moves. But are you sure it is not a different person?

Comment: Yeah, things do respawn if you use a checkpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [IGN Hitman: Absolution Wiki, "Checkpoints"](http://www.ign.com/wikis/hitman-absolution/Checkpoints) article:

> #### Mother-effing Checkpoints - How Do They Work?
>
> Checkpoints in Hitman Absolution only record objectives completed, the items (and ammo) currently carried by 47, his disguise, and his starting location.
>
> Nothing else is saved, due to the plasticity in the A.I. routes
> (targets speed up / slow down their paths as 47 is far / near a spot
> where they perform a specific task).
>
> Use checkpoints to your advantage for completing challenges. Sneak to
> a checkpoint and "start" the mission closer to a target (for example,
> [Death Factory](http://www.ign.com/wikis/hitman-absolution/Death_Factory)'s Testing Facility) or a spot where you can complete
> several challenges quickly without having to travel all the way across
> the map.
>
> Note that checkpoints do not work if enemies are fully alerted to 47's
> presence.